# finding values of $x$ in $Z$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all values of $x$ such that $\frac{x-4}{2x-3}\in\mathbb Z$?

I came up with this question to see if it could be solved based on some other questions I did myself. I thought this could not be done because if we substitute some numbers, the equation ends up being a rational number. I later did this:

$x-4$/$\frac{1}{2x-3}$

$=$ $(x-4)(2x-3)$

$=$ $2x^2-11x+12\in\mathbb Z$

I am not too sure where we can go from there. Can we set this equal to $0$? Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is an integer whenever $(2x - 3)$ divides $ (x - 4)$ evenly (with no remainder), correct? In other words, we can say that $(2x - 3)$ divides $(x - 4)$ evenly when there is some integer $n$ such that $n(2x - 3) = x - 4$. But this means that $$2nx - 3n = x - 4$$ We can get $x$ to one side and have  $$2nx - x = 3n - 4 \implies x(2n - 1) = 3n - 4 \implies x = \frac{3n - 4}{2n - 1}$$

So this is an integer whenever $x = \frac{3n - 4}{2n - 1}$ for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\left|\frac{x-4}{2x-3}\right|=\left|\frac 12-\frac{\frac 52}{2x-3}\right|\le \frac 12+\frac{5}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{|2x-3|}\le \frac 12+\frac 52\cdot 1=3.$$

Hence, we have
$$-3\le \frac{x-4}{2x-3}\le 3.$$
Then, finding $x\in\mathbb Z$ such that $$\frac{x-4}{2x-3}=k$$
for $k=-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$ gives you
$$x=-1,1,2,4.$$

Comment: Can you explain to me how you got the $1/2$ and the $5/2$

Comment: @col: I just divide $x-4$ by $2x-3$. The quotient is $1/2$ and the remainder is $-5/2$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I see where you get it now

Comment: @col: You are welcome. I'm glad to hear that.